# Does google search use data from Hidden fields

Tags: google-search-platform

I am building a website and there are few data points which I want to include in the page so that when user searches for it, my page should be shown in the google search. I don't want to show that data on the webpage though.
I am thinking to use hidden fields to store the data onto webpage.
Is this the correct approach? Will Google search pick data from hidden fields? If yes, is this a hack or legal?
Thanks for your help.
Cheers

Comment: It can get you penalized in some cases. https://www.searchenginejournal.com/hidden-text-seo/208866/

Comment: @AWebb thanks. this link helped me understand to an extent.